# GCM Android: onRegistered() not being called

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I'm having a problem with GCM on Android.  It fails to execute the `onRegistered()` callback, or ever return a good regId, on one of my test devices (Droid2) - but it works perfectly well on another device (Galaxy Nexus).

I'm following the basic example [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html).  The caller looks like this:

```
GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);

final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);

if (regId.equals(""))
    GCMRegistrar.register(this, Constants.SENDER_ID);
else
    Log.v(TAG, "Already registered");
```

And my manifest has this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

and

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        <category android:name="com.gcl.myapp" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Why isn't the `onRegistered()` callback working?  And what could be causing it to work on one device, but fail on another??  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it works on some devices but not others then it is to do with one of the following:

- Pre Android 4.0.4 the device requires a valid google account to work.
- GCM only works on devices with Play Store App and API 8 onwards.
- Your manifest is badly formatted - use Lint to check!
- Device/App is already registered, the Play implementation may not return again.. Try `GCMRegistrar.unregister(this);` first.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks @Chris.Jenkins.  The device it's not working on is running Android 2.3.4 (API level 10).  It has the Play Store installed, along with a valid Goggle account.  However, it has the same Google ID as the other/working device.  Could that pose a problem?

Comment: Nahh the Reg ID is device/app specific. Humm, if its not FC on the checks. Then that is very odd, can only assume that GCM is not working for anything on that device? Sync turned on?

Comment: also note that GCM was partially working on the older device (Droid2) at one point in the past.  At that time, like now, the onRegistered() call never returned, ... but the call to GCMRegistrar.register() did generated a good regId which I could use in the app.  I'm not sure what changed, but now neither GCMRegistrar.register() nor the onRegistered() callback is working.

Comment: You tried `GCMRegistrar.unregister(this);` then registering again. Wonder if older implementations dont call onRegister if the app is already 'registered'

Comment: Yes good idea, but I already tried that.  Let me do it again just to make sure.  In the meantime, any other ideas?

Comment: Err running out of ideas.. Try different connection? Restart your device..?

Comment: NP, thanks for your help.  I've restarted the device, but that didn't help.

Comment: I found my problem - it was just a typo in the manifest (but still not sure why it worked on one device and not the other).  Your suggestions were great, so I'll give you the check.  Thanks again.

Comment: Had the same issue! Worked on Galaxy Nexus, but not Nexus One. Had a typo (copy and paste from another project of mine) in the category of com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver. Thx. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. If you are using AngularJS + IonicFramework you do not have to do this:

After you create your factory with your onDeviceReady function, creates onNotificationGCM function. Something like this:

```
app.factory('PushProcessingService', function () {
..

});

function onNotificationGCM(e) {
}
```

I was creating onNotificationGCM inside my factory. This solve my problem.